# handling http calls from within an EJB transaction

Tags: ejb-3.0

This is the code I have:

//EJB

```
beanclass 1{

@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)
public String method1(){
 method2();
 DBupdates();

 return "";
}

}
```

//plain java class

```
class 2{
 method 2(){
   //call which may take a long time (but dont want to wait for it to complete)
   makes http calls to an external URL method();
}}
```

The issue is: the Http call may take a long time. However the response of the call decides the next steps in method1 -> db updates and response.the response needs to go back to the end-user, and i cannot make the end-user wait for ever.

i can handle this situation in two ways:

1. move method2 into the EJB and put TransactionAttributeType.NEVER, so that the http call is not in the transaction, and the transaction of method1 is not waiting on it. In this case, the container manages the transaction of method1 and does no db updates and returns null if it didnt hear back from method2. How long does the method1's transaction wait before "returning"?
2. i can use JBoss annotation and put a TransactionTimeout of 2 minutes on method1(): in this case, if http call does not complete within 2 minutes, method1 can return null and do no DB updates.

Which of these two methods is advisable and fault-proof?
Thanks for your insights.

Answer (score 0):

1. When you use `TransactionAttributeType.NEVER`, the transaction isn't propagated further.
   You can use `@Asynchronous` annotation for a method which returns `Future<V>` object. Then you can invoke `get(timeout, unit)` on the object to get the result type `V` which waits for the given time for manipulation, but it's EJB-3.1 specific.
2. Can try JBoss specific annotation `@TransactionTimeout` at method or class level. Also can configure it in jboss.xml or jboss-service.xml depending on your server version. This will be fine with EJB-3.0, but will loose portability of application.